# Is my African Grey's beak too long?

Tags: grooming, parrots

My mom says her parrot's beak is too long and she wants to get a clipper to trim it. I'm not so sure about this.

Is his beak too long, and if so, what can we do about it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://m.petmd.com/bird/care/overgrown-beak-birds-trimming-your-birds-beak

"If an owner suspects overgrowth of his or her bird’s beak, the bird should be checked by a veterinarian as soon as possible to rule-out underlying illness as the cause of overgrowth and to safely have the beak trimmed. The blood supply in an overgrown beak tends to be even longer than it is in a normal beak. Therefore, there is a significant risk of inducing bleeding when an overgrown beak is trimmed. As a result, owners really should never try to trim their birds’ beaks at home"

So please, take your parrot to the vet to ask their opinion.

Comment: Kai is absolutely right. I know what I'm doing, and I would never trim one of my birds' beaks. I would never trust even an experienced groomer to do it. Go to a qualified avian veterinarian. You can find an avian vet through the Association  of Avian Veterinarians (https://www.aav.org/search/custom.asp?id=1803).

Comment: We went to two different vets. The first one was quite inexperienced. Blood was lost :p The second knew what they were doing. Going to the vet for this was definitely the right decision.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too long; I just looked at my 2 Greys and their beaks look slightly less long. It is probably worth going to the right VET for a trim. Not all vets can handle parrots , you need to find the right vet. I use the local university vet department ; the vet clinic is part of the education program. It is not something for an amateur as there is a blood supply in part of the beak.